# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor DB Error

Tags: oracle11g, windows-7-x64

i installed oracle weblogic server and couldent configure it, when i tried to set the connections some errors occured.

i could trace out there is some issue with the database connection.

i have installed it on a single lenovo-pc, with windows professional x64.

IN WEB LOGIC SERVER:

i have given the jdbc name as "cmdemo" and the jndi name as "jdbc/cmdemo".

i have selected the oracle's driver as "(Thin) Instance Connections: Version: 9:0.1 and later".

i have selected the Supports Global Transactions options with one-phase commit in transaction options.

in the connection properties i gave database Name as "cmdemo", host name - "lenovo-pc", port - "1521", Db user name - "exp" Db Password - "exp".

when i try to "test configuration", the following error message is prompted...

Error Message:
Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:203)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:705)
com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:458)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
...
```

a solution for this will be a big favour...

regards,

Syed Hidayat

Answer (score 0):

Look at the listener status, if it is down pls ask the dba to get the listener up 
lsnrctl Status ( shows the status)
if down use the command : lsnrctl start ( to start)

if the issue still persists the check the listener file to have the instance entry if it is not present.

eg: `SID_LIST_LISTENER =
         (SID_LIST =
         (SID_DESC =
         (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
         (ORACLE_HOME = F:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
           (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:F:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
           )

          (SID_DESC = 
          (ORACLE_HOME =F:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (SID_NAME = example)
          )
          )`

edit the instance name from "example" to your instance name and restart the listener. You should see the instance in ready state in status output.

test by connecting `userid/pwd@instace_name` to check if the listener is up and connections are being picked via the service name. This should hopefully solve your problem.